# how to disregard specific new lines in reading from a text file by c++

Tags: c++, string

Wherever, there is a new line or ("\n") and a space (" ") immediately after the the new line, I want to disregard the "\n" and just print the space in my output, how could I do this?

This is an example:

```
newegg
 bizrate
```

want to change it to :

```
newegg bizrate
```

I am confused since I guess I cannot do it by reading line by line! below is my rough code, which I don't know how to continue ...
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
ifstream file ("input.txt");
ofstream output("output.txt");
string line;
if(file.is_open())
{
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        getline (file, line);
        if (line.find("\n"+' ') != string::npos)
        {
            ??
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this. The function getline() will read till `\n` character

```
getline(file, line);
cout<<line;
while (!file.eof())
{        
   getline(file, line);
   if (line[0]==' ')
   {
        cout <<" "<<line;
   }
   else
   {
         cout <<"\n"<<line;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `getline()` (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)) will read and throw away the `\n` character, so there's no need to search for it in the string.

Just do something like this:

```
bool first = true;
while (!file.eof())
{
    getline(file, line);

    // you may want to check that you haven't read the EOF here

    if (!first)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        first = false;
    }

    cout << line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want this:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream input(""
        "newegg\n"
        " bizrate\n"
        "End");
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(input, line)) {
        while(std::isspace(input.peek())) {
            std::string next_line;
            std::getline(input, next_line);
            line += next_line;
        }
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Please note: A test for EOF is likely wrong.